# Android Back Button does not work ?

Tags: android, button, back

I'm newbie on android development. I try to develop an app to store user expenses on db and show it on another activity.
When I press the back button on emulator, the app is shutting down.

I'm finishing the activity before the start intent? This could be a problem?

Comment: What do you want to achieve exactly?

Comment: finish the activity after startActivity (start intent)

Comment: @Fabian Thank you. delete finish() completely. It solved

Comment: @user2922744, please update your question with the exact problem so others can find it. Fabian, you can submit your resolution as an answer so it can be accepted and others can also benefit from it.

Comment: You should add that as an answer to your own question :-)

Comment: @thakrage I will thanks for the hint

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should first start the new activity before finishing the current one.

```
Intent i = net Intent(this.currentactivity, nextactivity.class);
startActivity(i);
finish();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK)) { 
            //WRITE YOUR LOGIC HERE
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Downvoted because it is not entirely clear what the problem exactly is, and usually you want to avoid messing with the back button like this. Usually the default lifecycle callbacks (onPause(), onStop() or onDestroy() can do exactly what you want).

Comment: It didn't, he removed a call to `finish()`, which is not what you suggested.